# An error while writing matrix into a raster file with rasterio

Tags: python, gis, tiff, rasterio

The original two datasets are two .tiff image file with same coordinate, height, width and transform information (let's say data1 and data2). I need to perform a simple math on them, but they both have null values, so I first use masked=True:

```
new1 = data1.read(1,masked=True)
new2 = data2.read(1,masked=True)
```

Then do the math:

```
target = new1 - new2
```

When I get the target, I try codes as below:

```
target.width
target.height
target.transform
target.crs
```

They all return the same error:

`'MaskedArray' object has no attribute 'xxx'(xxx represents all the attribute above: width, height, etc.)`

It seems the target loses all the information after math, I need to write this new result into a new raster file, what should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `read` method of a dataset, it will return a numpy array (masked in your case).
The numpy array is not a rasterio dataset, so it doesn't have those attributes.

To write it to disk you need to create a new profie (or copy the source dataset one) and use `rasterio.open` to create a new raster file:

```
profile = data1.profile
band_number = 1

# to update the dtype
profile.update(dtype=target.dtype)

with rasterio.open('raster.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(target, band_number)
```

See the [docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html) for a more detailed example

Comment: Thanks for the response, the method is correct, but there is another issue that there is a data type problem(dtype) during the process, the data1 is float32 but the target is int64, are there any ways to transfer?

Comment: your profile should match your data. You can update the dtype of the profile or convert the numpy array dtype. See edit above.
This is in the first example on the docs. Just take a moment to read there and you will understand easily